# UseEffect Infinite Loop Despite Empty Array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html-table, use-effect, infinite-loop

I know this error is being triggered because of the *TableBody* Since once I comment the lines within it, the *useEffect* gets fired only once.

I've read that if you use the empty array as second parameter for this function, it should be called only when component is mounted. But regardless of using it, useEffect is getting called recursively every time a Row in *TableBody* is appended.

I just want to fetch the users list once (when the component is rendered the first time). It used to work when it was a class component, but Im changing all my code to use only functional componentes, so Im unable to use **ComponentDidMount()** and that's what I'm trying to replace.

This is my Components Code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Backdrop from "@material-ui/core/Backdrop";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { formatDate } from "../../utilities";


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tablaMaterial: {
    minWidth: 800,
  },
  backdrop: {
    zIndex: 2,
    color: "#08eeff",
  }
}));

const UserList = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  
  const selectUser = (userId) => {
    console.log('who is calling me');
    let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/deleteUser'
    axios.post(baseUrl, {
      User_Id : userId})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      getAllUsers();
  }

  const getAllUsers = () => {
    console.log('did you call me');
    let baseUrl = "http://localhost:1337/getUsers";
    axios
    .get(baseUrl)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setUsers(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllUsers();
      }
    , []);
    
    return (
      <>
      <div class="Table">
        <h3 class="LabelTitleComponent">Lista de Empleados </h3>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow hover>
                <TableCell align="center">NAME</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">LAST NAME</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">ID NUMBER</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">DATE OF BIRTH</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">SALARY</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">WORKED HOURS</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">EMAIL</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">PHONE</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">ACTIONS</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {users.map((user, index) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow key={index}>
                    <TableCell align="left">{user.User_Name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{user.User_Last_Name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{user.Document_Id}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{formatDate(user.Birth_Date)}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{user.Salary}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{user.Weekly_Hours}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{user.User_Email}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{user.Phone_Number}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      <Button
                        align="center"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="secondary"
                        startIcon={<DeleteIcon align="center" />}
                        onClick={selectUser(user.User_Id)}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
      </>
    );
  }

export default UserList;
```

Note: There's also a very particular situation, even though Im never invoking **SelectUser** Method, its getting called in this recursive loop forever.

I would be more than glad to any suggestions, Im kind of stucked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking `selectUsers()` method:

```js
onClick={selectUser(user.User_Id)}
```

Change this to:

```js
onClick={() => selectUser(user.User_Id)}
```

Comment: I'm so Ashamed, Im too noob, thank you so much @Irfanullah Jan

Comment: It’s okay it happens to us all 